# Accesing variables in another function

Tags: python, function, variables

I need to make to be able to access variables from another function in the program. This is nothing major in terms of programming but it's something I need to know to build up more knowledge.

```
def s():
    v = 6 + 4
    a()
    return v

def a():
    ace = v + 4
    print(ace)

s()
```

Comment: In ``s()`` you have probably swapped the ``return v`` and ``a()`` statements. The way you have it now the ``a()`` does not get called as the ``s()`` returns before the call.

Comment: What are you trying to do? why do you `return` before calling `a` inside `s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to invoke the a function within another function then just pass your needed variable as a parameter! You also have a **return** within ***s*** that would cause your program to **return** before executing ***a***.
Ex...

```
def s():
    v = 6 + 4
    a(v)

def a(v):
    ace = v + 4
    print(ace)

s()
```

If you wanted to use a return then you could invoke one method as a parameter of another. This would allow you to use both methods independently of one another but it can get very messy!

```
def s():
    v = 6 + 4
    return v

def a(v):
    ace = v + 4
    print(ace)

a(s())
```

Good Luck and hope this helps!!

Comment: thank you can i pass multiple variables along functions like def a(v,word, position) etc?

Comment: Yes you can pass as many variables into a function as long as you specify that that function takes the same amount of parameters passed! This changes when using Lambdas, *args, and **kwargs but well leave that for another time!

Comment: No problem, If you feel like my answer or any other is good or if it solved your problem then please up vote and mark it as the correct answer to help people in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `return v` and `a()` calls in `s()` are unintentionally swapped, you can use the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement:

```
def s():
    global v
    v = 6 + 4
    a()
    return v

def a():
    ace = v + 4
    print(ace)

s()
```

Output:

```
14
```